# Counting number of occurrences in a time series for a set of condition(s)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: indicator time series - pivoted table]

I am required to do some summary statistics on the attached table as an example.
Some of the questions to answer include:

1) How many countries with valid time series (countries that have at least one value/number for a given indicator name over the time period of 2010-2015)
e.g: Count how many countries have valid times series for the indicator: "Number of completed applications"

2) For a given country and indicator what is the number of year(s) with valid time series.
e.g: For the indicator number of completed applications and the country Canada? (Answer: 2 --> 2014, 2015)

[image: indicator time series - flat table]

Alternatively, if the table look like this instead (which is a typical csv format) what approach could be taken to answer the two summary statistics questions above?

I have tried method of sumproduct formula for the pivoted table. Is there a better way than this method?

> =SUMPRODUCT(N((B2:B14>0)+(C2:C14>0)+(D2:D14>0)+(E2:E14>0)+(F2:F14>0)+(G2:G14>0)+(H2:H14>0)+(I2:I14>0)+(J2:J14>0)>0))

But what about when it is a flat table?

Comment: Is any other year than 2010-2015 included in your data? Furthermore, do these countries come as repetitive as it seems in your sample data, e.g. 1,2,3,1,2,3?

Comment: Have you tried countifs()

Comment: @JvdV there could be other years, but this is just a sample. There could be more countries, but I was just trying to simplify the sample frame.

Comment: Sorry, don't go to links... But check out my example given in an answer.

Comment: Thanks for that example in your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, an example of countifs() and also sumifs():

[image: Example for Solar Mike]

*From Nevsky -- Thanks a lot for the example! I took the liberty to modify it a bit as follows* :
[image]