# Sum several rows in a column based on criteria in 2 other columns

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to figure out if there is an easier way to be able to calculate what I am doing. I want a running count of my inventory of each type of map I sell. In row 9 in the picture provided will show the user the total quantity of each map they sell so that they know when to order or get more. Basically, I select from a drop down list what kind of map I am selling then I will put in the quantity and then select the transaction or tender method. If the tender method is "AD 107+" it needs to add the quantity entered to the total inventory of that specific map selected but it the tender type is "CASH", "CHECK", "PLASTIC", or "AD 107-" then the quantity entered needs to be subtracted from the inventory. What I have set up for a formula now is working but I feel like there is an easier way whether it be a formula or some VBA code.

Here is the link to my excel spreadsheet and is on the sheet labeled Maps.

[Click Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=180f4KrS3mzv1kKTyWmHeKF1RYfp_CJYN)

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/57376499/4961700

Comment: @Solar Mike I looked at that and I dont think that would work for what I am needing it for.

Comment: Well, I used countifs() to get a result based on the country and if it was completed or not. Change country for map type ie edit to match your situation. Just clicked on your link and it seems to be about wood tags... not maps...

Comment: So there is a sheet for Maps. I have 2 sheets in this workbook. The first sheet is Wood Tags and the second one is Maps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original formula in Cell **A9** on the **Maps** sheet is as follow which is **not making sense** as you can see below you summed **AD 107+** twice and subtracted **AD 107+** once which is unnecessary, besides **you did not account for 'AD 107-'** as mentioned in your question.

```
=(SUMIFS(E11:E21,B11:B21,A8,F11:F21,"AD 107+"))+

(SUMIFS(E11:E21,B11:B21,A8,F11:F21,"CASH")*-1)+

(SUMIFS(E11:E21,B11:B21,A8,F11:F21,"CHECK")*-1)+

(SUMIFS(E11:E21,B11:B21,A8,F11:F21,"PLASTIC")*-1)+

(SUMIFS(E11:E21,B11:B21,A8,F11:F21,"AD 107+")*-1)+

(SUMIFS(E11:E21,B11:B21,A8,F11:F21,"AD 107+"))
```

A corrected formula should be something like the follow:

```
=(SUMIFS(E11:E21,B11:B21,A8,F11:F21,"AD 107+"))+

(SUMIFS(E11:E21,B11:B21,A8,F11:F21,"CASH")*-1)+

(SUMIFS(E11:E21,B11:B21,A8,F11:F21,"CHECK")*-1)+

(SUMIFS(E11:E21,B11:B21,A8,F11:F21,"PLASTIC")*-1)+

(SUMIFS(E11:E21,B11:B21,A8,F11:F21,"AD 107-")*-1)
```

I have revised the above as below which might or not might not be short enough for you:

```
=-SUMIF(B11:B21,A8,E11:E21)+SUMIFS(E11:E21,B11:B21,A8,F11:F21,"AD 107+")*2
```

The logic is that

> firstly sum up the quantity in Column E based on the map type in cell
>   A8, then take out the quantity with tender type 'AD 107+' **twice** so
>   it is effective 'subtracting' the 'AD 107+' quantity from the total.

You can use the same logic to rewrite your formulas in cell D9, G9 and I9.

By the way I think the way you structured the Maps sheet is not ideal. For instance I cannot easily drag the formula across the row as you have merged the cells. It would be a huge obstacle for editing and examining formulas.

Comment: Yes, That works. Thank you. I would give a +1 but I dont have 15 reputation yet. Also I will undo the Merged Cells to make it a bit more easier for editing and copying formulas like you mentioned.

Comment: Good to now it worked. If my answer is fine you may **accept my answer as the solution** by clicking the 'tick' mark underneath the down-vote button? No fuss :)